# like icon in flutter video player not work in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am going to use videobox to display videos. And I want to display a like icon on the video. I used the following codes for this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_box/video_box.dart';

class PlayOne extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;
  const PlayOne({Key? key,required this.id}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlayOne> createState() => _PlayOneState();
}

class _PlayOneState extends State<PlayOne> {
  bool loadedData = true;
  late VideoController video;
  bool toggle = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    video.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: loadedData? const Center(
        child: RefreshProgressIndicator(),
      ):
      AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: VideoBox(
          controller: video,
          customLoadingWidget: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Text('please wait', style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11, color: Colors.white))
                ],
              )
          ),
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.03,
              child: Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.15,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                icon: toggle
                                    ? const Icon(Icons.favorite_border)
                                    : const Icon(
                                  Icons.favorite,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    toggle = !toggle;
                                  });
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void loadData(){
    setState(() {
      video = VideoController(
          source: VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
              Uri.parse('video link')
          )
      )..initialize();
      loadedData = false;
    });
  }
}
```

I have used the same codes on other pages and it works correctly, but when I use it in the video player. Does not workBut when I click on the icon, nothing happens.
Is the problem with the video player or is there another solution?